# Spark - how to get filename with parent folder from dataframe column

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I am using pyspark as code language. I added column to get filename with path.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
data = data.withColumn("sourcefile",input_file_name())
```

I want to retrieve only filename with it's parent folder from this column. Please help.

Example:

```python
Inputfilename = "adl://dotdot.com/ingest/marketing/abc.json"
```

What output I am looking for is:

```python
marketing/abc.json
```

Note: String operation I can do. The filepath column is part of dataframe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to keep the value in a dataframe column you could use the pyspark.sql.function regexp_extract. You can apply it to the column with the value of path and passing the regular expression required to extract the desired part:

```
data = data.withColumn("sourcefile",input_file_name())

regex_str = "[\/]([^\/]+[\/][^\/]+)$"
data = data.withColumn("sourcefile", regexp_extract("sourcefile",regex_str,1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I would like to keep last 2 parent directories instead of just one? For e.g. ingest/marketing/abc.json. Can this be parameterized to take total number of directories to return?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is :

```
sc.wholeTextFiles('path/to/files').map(
    lambda x : ( '/'.join(x[0].split('/')[-2:]), x[1])
)
```

This create a rdd with 2 columns, 1st one is the `path to file`, second one is the content of the file. That is the only way to link a path and a content in spark. 
Other method exists in Hive for example.

Comment: I want to keep `files/file1.json` as value in dataframe column

Answer (score 0):

The input_file_name() function wasn't working reliably for me when using spark 3.3.2, delta_spark 2.3.0, and delta-parquet files; instead, the following seems to work better:

```
regex_str = "[\/]([^\/]+[\/][^\/]+)$"
data = data.withColumn("sourcefile", regexp_extract("_metadata.file_path",regex_str,1))
```

Also, if using Databricks, according to the following link,  input_file_name is deprecated: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/input_file_name.html

> In Databricks SQL and Databricks Runtime 13.1 and above this function
> is deprecated. Please use _metadata.file_name.